# Combine objects in an array based on common key values in Logic Apps

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array, key, azure-logic-apps

So I have output from an API that can look something like this

```
[
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100002",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 1",
    "to_Item": "",
    "SalesOrderItem": "10",
    "Material": "TG22",
    "RequestedQuantity": "1"
},
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100002",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 1",
    "to_Item": "",
    "SalesOrderItem": "20",
    "Material": "TG0011",
    "RequestedQuantity": "1"
},
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100010",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 2",
    "to_Item": "",
    "SalesOrderItem": "10",
    "Material": "TG0011",
    "RequestedQuantity": "2"
},
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100010",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 2",
    "to_Item": "",
    "SalesOrderItem": "20",
    "Material": "TG22",
    "RequestedQuantity": "3"
},
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100010",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 3",
    "to_Item": "",
    "SalesOrderItem": "10",
    "Material": "TG22",
    "RequestedQuantity": "1"
}]
```

Now what I want is to merge all objects that have the same "PurchaseOrderByCustomer" into an array with a nested array that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100002",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 1",
    "to_Item": [
        {
             "SalesOrderItem": "10",
             "Material": "TG22",
             "RequestedQuantity": "1"
        },
        {
         "SalesOrderItem": "20",
             "Material": "TG0011",
             "RequestedQuantity": "1"
        }
        ]
},
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100010",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 2",
    "to_Item": [
        {
         "SalesOrderItem": "10",
             "Material": "TG0011",
                 "RequestedQuantity": "2"
        },
        {
             "SalesOrderItem": "20",
             "Material": "TG22",
             "RequestedQuantity": "3"
        }
        ]
},
{
    "SalesOrderType": "OR",
    "SalesOrganization": "1710",
    "DistributionChannel": "10",
    "OrganizationDivision": "00",
    "SoldToParty": "17100010",
    "TransactionCurrency": "USD",
    "PurchaseOrderByCustomer": "SalesOrder Simulate 3",
    "to_Item": [
        {
             "SalesOrderItem": "10",
             "Material": "TG22",
             "RequestedQuantity": "1"
        }
        ]
}]
```

So one Sales Order can have multiple Items and one sales order needs to be one object in the format I need to further process the order. Now I want to do this in Logic Apps and I have tried several stuff but I'm completely lost and not even sure if this is even possible within Logic Apps to accomplish this.

I would like to know if what I need is even possible in Logic Apps

Comment: Try to write a plain JS code that does the above actual-to-expected transform. Once the code is ready, you can execute that code using the built-in *Inline Code* action (supports only JS as of now) of Logic Apps. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Nikhil Vartak` mentioned in the comments, you can use [Inline Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) to achieve your purpose：

You can refer to my code:

```
var jsonString=<your-json>;
var pur=[];
for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(jsonString).length;i++){
    pur.push(jsonString[i].PurchaseOrderByCustomer);
}
var arr=[...new Set(pur)];
var array=[];
var num;
var jsonArray=[];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var purchaseOrder = arr[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < Object.keys(jsonString).length; j++){
        var item = jsonString[j];
        if(item.PurchaseOrderByCustomer == purchaseOrder){
            var to = {"SalesOrderItem": item.SalesOrderItem,"Material": item.Material,"RequestedQuantity": item.RequestedQuantity};
            array.push(to);
        }
    }
for(var j = 0;j<Object.keys(jsonString).length;j++){
    if(jsonString[j].PurchaseOrderByCustomer==purchaseOrder){
        num=j;
        break;
    }
}
var item=jsonString[num];
item.to_Item=array;
delete item['SalesOrderItem'];
delete item['Material'];
delete item['RequestedQuantity'];
jsonArray.push(item);
array=[];
}
return jsonArray;
```

I did some tests and the results seem to be no problem：

[image]

Note:

If you use `Inline Code` in `Azure Logic App`, you need to add an [integration accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account?tabs=azure-portal).

Comment: This was the solution to my problem, thanks a lot!