# logic apps dictionary variables

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I think I want to use a dictionary variable in my logic apps. The [contains function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#contains) seems useful to me, especially if my collection is a dictionary.  I can't see how to Initialize a variable as a dictionary, though. Have any of you done anything like that?

More specifically,

I get a collection of objects from an API like:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Mr. Test Smith",
    "Type": "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Mr. Test Smith",
    "Type": "DISPATCH"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Different Name",
    "Type": "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE"
  }
]
```

I want to 'merge' them, using name as a key, to get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Mr. Test Smith",
    "Types": [
      "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE",
      "DISPATCH"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Different Name",
    "Types": [
      "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: That’s not properly formed JSON though. Are you sure you’re getting that back exactly as described? Paste your JSON in a “beautifier” online and you’ll see it doesn’t work. You can’t have `{"Mr. Test Smith", "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE"}` as that’s technically an array but it’s encapsulated in object syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I manually typed in that example. I think I've corrected it to be properly formed JSON.

Comment: Do you need to do this to conform to a format required by another application or is there some other reason?

Comment: Yes, I am essentially conforming to a format required by a Salesforce app. It stores contacts keyed by Name (e.g., "Mr. Test Smith") with a collection of properties (e.g., "Types": [
      "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE",
      "DISPATCH"
    ])

I need to avoid duplicate contacts, so I need to transform the input, which has a separate object for each Name/Type combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can call api from http trigger or action and initialize response from api into an array variable.

- Used a HTTP trigger in logic app and assigned body of api response to an array variable as shown below,
  [image]
- Payload of http trigger is,

```
{
  "items": {
    "properties": {
      "Name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Type": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "Name",
      "Type"
    ],
    "type": "object"
  },
  "type": "array"
}
```

- The variable value will be assigned like this,
  [image]

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Mr. Test Smith",
    "Type": "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Mr. Test Smith",
    "Type": "DISPATCH"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Different Name",
    "Type": "ACCOUNTSPAYABLE"
  }
]
```

- Once value assigned to variable, use inline action to merge objects
  based on Name property as mentioned [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332974/combine-objects-in-an-array-based-on-common-key-values-in-logic-apps)

Comment: That inline JavaScript solution looks promising. I'll pursue that.

My curiosity about dictionary variables persists, though. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#contains) implies contains could do almost exactly what I need, without JavaScript.